# Angular 2 - @Input not updating model on super component

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I have the following scenario:

There are some entities that own `Pessoa`, one of these is `Administrador`, so I decided to create a component to wrap the `Pessoa` data on CRUD forms. I bound the `administrador.pessoa` property to my new `PessoaFormComponent` with the `@Input()` directive.

My problem is that when I submit the `AdministradorComponent` form, the `administrador.pessoa` property remains null, like if the updates on `pessoa` property of `PessoaFormComponent` were not reflected into `AdministradorComponent`.

administrador.component.ts:

```
@Component({
...
templateUrl: './administrador.component.html',
directives: [... PessoaFormComponent, ...],
...
})
export class AdministradorComponent {
  @ViewChild('pessoaForm')
  pessoaFormComponent: PessoaFormComponent;
}
```

administrador.component.html:

```
...
<app-pessoa-form #pessoaForm [(pessoa)]="entidade.pessoa"></app-pessoa-form>
...
```

pessoa.form.component.ts:

```
@Component({
...
selector: 'app-pessoa-form',
templateUrl: './pessoa.form.component.html',
...
})
export class PessoaFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input()
  pessoa: Pessoa;

  private _tipoPessoa: String;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
   this._tipoPessoa= 'FISICA';
   this.reiniciarPessoa();
 }

 private reiniciarPessoa() {
   if (this._tipoPessoa === 'JURIDICA') {
     this.pessoa = new PessoaJuridica();;
   } else {
     this.pessoa = new PessoaFisica();;
   }
 }

 get tipoPessoa(): String {
   return this._tipoPessoa;
 }

 set tipoPessoa(tipoPessoa: String) {
   this._tipoPessoa = tipoPessoa;
   this.reiniciarPessoa();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `[(pessoa)]="entidade.pessoa"` this syntax to work you need an `@Input()` and `@Output()` combination where the output name is `pessoaChange` and value changes need to be emitted using `this.pessoaChange.emit(newValue)`

```
export class PessoaFormComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input()
  pessoa: Pessoa;

  @Output()
  pessoaChange:EventEmitter<Pessoa> = new EventEmitter<Pessoa>();

  private reiniciarPessoa() {
    if (this._tipoPessoa === 'JURIDICA') {
      this.pessoa = new PessoaJuridica();
    } else {
      this.pessoa = new PessoaFisica();;
    }
    this.pessoaChange.emit(this.pessoa);
  }
```